# VBA Excel: Like operator does not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba, cyrillic, vb-like-operator

Why `Like` function does not work? In this case it returns:

> "No, it's not"

```
Sub test()
    If "*ыписка по договору ук-004#1500333*" Like "выписка по договору ук-004#1500333 стд.xlsx" Then
        MsgBox "Yes, it is!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No, it's not"
    End If    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the strings backwards.

```
If {string} Like {substring w/wildcards} Then
```

---

```
Sub test()
    If "выписка по договору ук-004#1500333 стд.xlsx" Like "*ыписка по договору ук-004#1500333*" Then
        MsgBox "Yes, it is!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No, it's not"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: another thing is the # character is a wildcard for a number. so you would need to encapsulated it using [#] so it would look like 
If "выписка по договору ук-004#1500333 стд.xlsx" Like "*ыписка по договору ук-004[#]1500333*" Then

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `InStr` instead if your goal is to verify the existence of a string in another:

```
Sub test()   
    If  InStr("выписка по договору ук-004#1500333 стд.xlsx", _
        "ыписка по договору ук-004#1500333") > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Yes, it is!"
    Else
        MsgBox "No, it's not"
    End If    
End Sub
```